# Nested User Control (ListView) in ListView doesn't get bound

Tags: asp.net, listview, controls, nested

Hi I am trying to implement a nested user control in listview and the user control doesn't get bound.
Here is my code.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewTaskList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="TaskID"
DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceTaskList" OnItemDataBound="ListViewTaskListItemDataBound" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder">
<LayoutTemplate>
    <div class="ListView ">
        <div style="font-size:2em;color:#555555;margin-bottom:20px;">Task List</div>
        <div ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
        </div>
    </div>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="rlvI">
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="TaskIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TaskID") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="TaskLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Task") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="CreatedDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CreatedDate") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="UpdatedDateLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UpdatedDate") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="TimestampLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Timestamp") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="TaskTypeIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TaskTypeID") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="ProjectTaskStatusIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProjectTaskStatusID") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="SystemObjectIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SystemObjectID") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="SystemObjectRecordIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SystemObjectRecordID") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:CheckBox ID="ActiveCheckBox" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>' Enabled="false" />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="CreatedByAccountIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CreatedByAccountID") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="UpdatedByAccountIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UpdatedByAccountID") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select" CssClass="rlvBSel" Text=" " ToolTip="Select" />
        <div>
            <Enet:Comments ID="Comments1" runat="server" systemObjectID='8' systemObjectRecordID="Comments1Init" />
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <div class="rlvA">
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="TaskIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TaskID") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="TaskLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Task") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="CreatedDateLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("CreatedDate") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="UpdatedDateLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("UpdatedDate") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="TimestampLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("Timestamp") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="TaskTypeIDLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("TaskTypeID") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="ProjectTaskStatusIDLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("ProjectTaskStatusID") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="SystemObjectIDLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("SystemObjectID") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="SystemObjectRecordIDLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("SystemObjectRecordID") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:CheckBox ID="ActiveCheckBox" runat="server" 
            Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>' Enabled="false" />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="CreatedByAccountIDLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("CreatedByAccountID") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="UpdatedByAccountIDLabel" runat="server" 
            Text='<%# Eval("UpdatedByAccountID") %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="SelectButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
            CommandName="Select" CssClass="rlvBSel" Text=" " ToolTip="Select" />
            <div>
                <Enet:Comments ID="Comments1" runat="server" systemObjectID='8' '<%# Eval("TaskID") %>' />
            </div>
    </div>
</AlternatingItemTemplate>
```

``

I have been struggling with this problem for a few days now.
Please help!!
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

if I look at your code, it seems to me that you aren't actually assigning the binding to anything:

```
<Enet:Comments ID="Comments1" runat="server" systemObjectID='8' '<%# Eval("TaskID") %>' />
```

try instead

```
<Enet:Comments ID="Comments1" runat="server" systemObjectID='8' YourProperty='<%# Eval("TaskID") %>' />
```

EDIT: in order to achieve two way data binding, one has to add BindableAttribute to the property on User Control

Comment: Hi I am sorry. My bad. Actually there was a code to bind that value and and I accidentally deleted it. Even though I bind the value as your code. The value is still not bound to the user control. I traced it and noticed that no value was passed. One things I noticed though was the user control get called first before the listview gets called. Is that normal? If that is the case there was no way the user control gets the value needed.

Comment: Hi this could help: http://forums.asp.net/t/1181422.aspx Try to add BindableAttribute to that property on UserControl. Hope this helps

Comment: This is the code behind for the user control. Is this how you do it. Thank you so much. `code`[Browsable(true)]
 [Bindable(true, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
 [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.Attribute)]
 
 public partial class TaskList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
 {

  // SystemObjectID for Task = 8
  public int systemObjectIDSave { get; set; }
  // SystemsBojectID dependent to
  public int systemObjectID { get; set; }
  //public int systemObejctRecordID { get; set; }
  public int accountID { get; set; }
  public string userName { get; set; }
  public int userTypeID { get; set; } `code`

Comment: you should place Bindable attribute on the property level, not class level, as explained for example here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1132704.aspx/1

Comment: Hi Robert, Thank you so much for your answers. I tried setting like [Bindable(true)] public int systemObjectID{ get;set; } but no luck. My project depends on this. Could you help?

Comment: that's weird. Then try to override ItemDataBound event and set the property there,  for example as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207147/databinding-a-list-to-a-usercontrol-in-an-item-template-in-codebehind

Comment: Hi Robert, Unfortunately no matter what I try, it just doesn't work... Thanks for all your help.